# Sum the rows in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to sum up two columns in the gridview and show the total in the labels. I have paging enabled in the gridview.

Using this code I sum the totals of two columns, however, the total is for the selected page only.

How can I do a **grand total** to sum all the rows for selected columns from all the pages?

```
    decimal priceTotal = 0;
    int totalMinutes = 0;
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            priceTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Total"));
            totalMinutes += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Duration"));
        }
        lblTotalPrice.Text = "Total Cost: $"+ priceTotal.ToString();
        lblTotalMinutes.Text = "Total duration: " + totalMinutes.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: I have, but I just don't want to call another query or procedure just to return the sums when I know I can loop through the gridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
decimal price = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView.Rows)
{
     price += row.Cells["Total"]!=null ? Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["Total"].Value) : 0;
}

lblTotalPrice.Text = "Total Cost: $"+ price.ToString("n2");
```

Comment: I get the following error `The name DataGridview does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: I have, and I get different error `The type or namespace name DataGridViewRow could not be found...`

Comment: I have tried that too. It doesn't like `row.Cells["Total"] overload`